# jquery ui autocomplete database

Tags: database, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'd like to use jQuery UI autocomplete in order to load a list from my database but I don't know wich method I should use to do so.

I tried to use the "Remote datasource" method http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote, but it obviously doesn't work.

I have the following code :

js:

```
$(function() {
    $("#client").autocomplete({
    source: "nom.php",
    minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
        alert(ui);
        }
    });
});
```

html :

```
<label for="client">Client</label>
<input name="client" id="client" class="ui-autocomplete ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
```

php:

```
$query = "SELECT nom from personne";
$result = mysql_query($query, $db);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

foreach($row as $val)
    $tab[] = $val;

}

print json_encode($tab);
```

It does show all the values no matter what I enter, but when I copy the result of nom.php and past it next to source: it does work...

thank you for your helm

Comment: This should work. You have to check your logs, maybe do some very light javascript debugging with a tool like firebug (just to check if function is well called, and that 'nom.php' is called and returns good data).

Comment: I actually don't understand how this autocomplete works : 
when I debug with firefox I see that the response is ["Marion","AM","PE","AH","JP","FD"] no matter what I write, I expect the autocomplete to select the good values from this list, but it doesn't. When I write 
source: ["Marion","AM","PE","AH","JP","FD"], it does work properly.

Comment: I've found some kind of workaround but I'd prefer to understand what is wrong in my code. Here is the workaround: $query = "SELECT nom from employe WHERE nom LIKE '%" . addslashes($_GET['term']) . "%'";

Comment: yes, you need to filter the items using a where clause... definitely...

Comment: you might also want to only select a limited number of results, say, the top 10/20 for example, maybe order them too

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are not filtering the results server side.

When you use a local collection, the local collection gets automatically filtered by autocomplete.

However, when using a remote source, the source is supposed to filter. I guess this is to save bandwidth so that the server only send the matching items, and not all items and let the browser filter at it's end.

When calling your server side method, autocomplete also sends a parameter called `term` that you can use to filter.

You can get hold of the entered value like this in your php script:

```
 $term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));
```

Then in your `foreach`, only add the items matching the filter to your collection before you send it back again.